# Personalize form field name (with formset)

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like personalize the field name render like with **auto_id**. Some code:

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
>>> class MyForm(forms.Form):
...   name = forms.CharField()
... 
>>> myform_formset = formset_factory(MyForm)
>>> print myform_formset(auto_id='my_form_%s')

<input id="my_form_form-TOTAL_FORMS" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" [...]
<tr><th><label for="my_form_form-0-name">Name:</label></th><td>
<input id="my_form_form-0-name" name="form-0-name" type="text" /></td></tr>
```

Ids are personalizeds: id=" **my_form_** form-0-name". Actually, field names are render like this: name="form-0-name". I would like render them like name=" **my_form_** form-0-name".

Why i need it ? I've two differents formset in my form, so i've multiple field with name "form-0-name" and it's not good for POST data.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what you would like to get for output?

Comment: Added content in my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `prefix` argument to `myform_formset`

```
myform_formset = formset_factory(MyForm)
print myform_formset(prefix="my_form")


<td><input id="id_my_form-1-name" name="my_form-1-name" type="text" /></td></tr>
```

Comment: Perfect. I will use it in replacement of auto_id to.